# What are the best apps for backing up and restoring a Linux/Ubuntu machine?

Tags: linux, backup

They should be quick in restoring and backing up the computer.

And you should be able to install an ISO on a CD or a USB flash drive and boot from that and restore the computer from backups on a separate partition on the machine or on another machine in the network or even in the USB flash drive or CD.

Comment: `tar` and `dd` have been used successfully in the past.

Comment: I suppose you could install a second USB drive, say /sdb and use `dd` to do a bit-by-bit copy of your entire drive to it. It should even be bootable, so you could change your bios to boot from it. I wouldn't keep it plugged in, though, as it would have the same UUID as the original. If you use this method, you should test your copy by booting from it **before** you need it.

Comment: Do you mean do a full backup or an incremental one? What kind of support do you need for removable media (e.g. “insert Tuesday's tape”)? Do you only need full system recovery or also e.g. recovery of one file that has been deleted by accident?

Comment: @Marc I agree that you should always test this kind of stuff before you use it to make sure it does what you need it to without any problems.

Comment: @Gilles I need to be able to recover just the OS and I need something that'll do a full backup and something that'll do snapshots type backups (which are kind of like incremental but really fast to create and restore and take up a lot less storage space). I use [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/pc-backup) in Windows for full backups and than something like [Rollback RX](http://horizondatasys.com/en/products_and_solutions.aspx?ProductId=1) for snapshot type backups. There's more information at the links.